# Apple TV accepts Airplay screen mirroring from 1 account on my Mac, but not the other account. Mac Keychain issue?

Tags: macos, keychain, airplay

My setup: 4th Gen Apple TV and Macbook Pro running Mojave

Mac has two accounts... "WorkAccount" and "HomeAccount".

When I try to mirror the Mac screen to Apple TV, it works fine from one account "WorkAccount", but when I use the other account "HomeAccount" the Mac says "Could not connect to MYATV" after typing the challenge code that shows on the TV screen.

Note: If I change the ATV settings to use a password, which eliminates the challenge code, the screen mirroring works fine from either Mac account.

But I need to fix the issue on the Mac because other Airplay devices - like my Vizio TV - do not have the option to set a passwword.

Both Mac accounts have admin permissions.

The only difference I can think of is the one with trouble, "HomeAccount", was migrated from another Mac, although everything else seems to work fine.